# Material-UI Rating returns string instead of number

Tags: javascript, reactjs, types, material-ui, onchange

I am running into a problem with the Material UI rating component.

I want it to return a number when I change it, but it returns a string. The initial value I provide (this.props.data.feelings_rating) is a number, but whenever I change it in my app it becomes a string. Here is the relevant code:

Rating component:

```
<Rating
          value={this.props.data.feelings_rating}
          name="feelings_rating"
          onChange={handleChange}
          size="large"
          getLabelText={(value) => customIcons[value].label}
          IconContainerComponent={IconContainer}
        />
```

handleChange:

```
handleChange = (e) => {
    var diary = this.state.diary
    diary[e.name] = e.value
    this.setState({diary: diary})
  }
```

other stuff to do with the icons:

```
const customIcons = {
  1: {
    icon: <SentimentVeryDissatisfiedIcon />,
    label: 'Very Dissatisfied',
  },
  2: {
    icon: <SentimentDissatisfiedIcon />,
    label: 'Dissatisfied',
  },
  3: {
    icon: <SentimentSatisfiedIcon />,
    label: 'Neutral',
  },
  4: {
    icon: <SentimentSatisfiedAltIcon />,
    label: 'Satisfied',
  },
  5: {
    icon: <SentimentVerySatisfiedIcon />,
    label: 'Very Satisfied',
  },
};

function IconContainer(props) {
  const { value, ...other } = props;
  return <span {...other}>{customIcons[value].icon}</span>;
}

IconContainer.propTypes = {
  value: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
};
```

I cannot find anyone else on the internet with this problem, so can anyone spot what I am doing wrong? Any answers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `onChange` of the Rating component gives you 2 arguments one is the event object and the other is actual value. You can retrive the selected value from the second argument `newValue`

```
handleChange = (e, newValue) => {
    // create a copy of the state
    const clonedDiary = {...this.state.diary}
    // now mutate the clonedDiary directly
    clonedDiary[e.name] = newValue;
    this.setState({diary: clonedDiary })
 }
```

**Refer**

[Rating API](https://next.material-ui.com/api/rating/)